# Use Object's value to determine output - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object here:

```
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};
```

Basically this is a list of object of each names and the number of their visits.

If Mike was set up on the function which has 1 visit it will console.log('One')

Example:

```
var result = hi('Mike');
console.log(result); => 'One'
```

If Roland was set up on the function which has 2 visits it will console.log('two')

Comment: Loop through the array inside this function to find the visits for the person passed into the function and console.log the visits.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`Object.keys()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_6vH2rtPTAhVBHJQKHVMdAQ0QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw&sig2=5aG0RqbNW-vBnBSlu84aXQ) and [`Array#includes`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCgICbr9PTAhWQNpQKHYpWBwYQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fincludes&usg=AFQjCNH5UxAefwkcnRMTtq3VoGcYGJuHDg&sig2=B1zCPYOqHKHW7pinz1Dzlw) methods .i was added the `num` array for showing the resultant string *`eg:three`* instead of `integer` .created `num` array upto `five`.better use with value in `string` instead of `integer` inside the object. like

```
'Mike': {
    visits: 'one'
        },
```

```js
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};
var num=['zero','one','two','three','four','five']

function hi(firstname) {
  if (Object.keys(visits).includes(firstname)) {
    console.log(num[visits[firstname].visits])
  } else {
    console.log('welcome')
  }
}

hi('Chiks');
hi('new')
```

Comment: So whats additional info is there in this answer that it got 2 upvotes and other same one got downvotes?

Comment: He is expecting 'three' NOT 3 for `Chiks`. Bsically not integers.

Comment: @prasad you don't need to get the keys collection first and then check for includes and then again read the value from the object. Just checking once and then deciding what to output should be enough. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

function hi(firstName) {
  var msg = 'Welcome ' + firstName;

  var person = visits[firstName]
  if (person && person.visits) {
    switch (person.visits) {
      case 1:
        msg = "One";
        break;
      case 2:
        msg = "Two";
        break;
      default:
        msg = "Three";
        break
    }
  }
  console.log(msg)
  return msg
}

hi('Mike')
hi('Rols')
hi('Roland')
hi('New person')
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your object and compare. This code prints digit up to 9 [1-9].

```js
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

var digits={
 1:'one',
 2:'two',
 3:'three',
 4:'four',
 5:'five',
 6:'six',
 7:'seven',
 8:'eight',
 9:'nine'
};

function getDigit(digit){
 return digits[digit];
}

function hi(firstName){
 if(typeof visits[firstName]!='undefined' && visits[firstName]['visits']!='' && typeof visits[firstName]['visits']!='undefined'){
     console.log(getDigit(visits[firstName]['visits']));
 }else{
     console.log('welcome');
 }
}


hi('Rols');
hi('Roland');
hi('ge');
```

Working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/gupz1hf7/).

Comment: Why have you changed the input? It was suppose to be object, not array

Answer (score 0):

Here I got generic solution to print as you expected. Please check the solution in this [Working example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF9B1084GR4J).

you can extend you object visits to any number with other values as well (like I have added 'Ponc').
{
      'Mike': {
        visits: 1
      },
      'Roland': {
        visits: 2
      },
      'Chiks': {
        visits: 3
      },
      'Rols': {
        visits: 4
      },
      'Ponc': {
        visits: 5
      }
.......
    };

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label for='numinput'>Number To Display :</label>
<input type='text' id='numinput' name='numinput'></input>
<div id='output'></div>

<script>
function numToWords(number) {

    //Validates the number input and makes it a string
    if (typeof number === 'string') {
        number = parseInt(number, 10);
    }
    if (typeof number === 'number' && isFinite(number)) {
        number = number.toString(10);
    } else {
        return 'This is not a valid number';
    }

    //Creates an array with the number's digits and
    //adds the necessary amount of 0 to make it fully 
    //divisible by 3
    var digits = number.split('');
    while (digits.length % 3 !== 0) {
        digits.unshift('0');
    }


    //Groups the digits in groups of three
    var digitsGroup = [];
    var numberOfGroups = digits.length / 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++) {
        digitsGroup[i] = digits.splice(0, 3);
    }
    console.log(digitsGroup); //debug

    //Change the group's numerical values to text
    var digitsGroupLen = digitsGroup.length;
    var numTxt = [
        [null, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'], //hundreds
        [null, 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'], //tens
        [null, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'] //ones
        ];
    var tenthsDifferent = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];

    // j maps the groups in the digitsGroup
    // k maps the element's position in the group to the numTxt equivalent
    // k values: 0 = hundreds, 1 = tens, 2 = ones
    for (var j = 0; j < digitsGroupLen; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            var currentValue = digitsGroup[j][k];
            digitsGroup[j][k] = numTxt[k][currentValue];
            if (k === 0 && currentValue !== '0') { // !==0 avoids creating a string "null hundred"
                digitsGroup[j][k] += ' hundred ';
            } else if (k === 1 && currentValue === '1') { //Changes the value in the tens place and erases the value in the ones place
                digitsGroup[j][k] = tenthsDifferent[digitsGroup[j][2]];
                digitsGroup[j][2] = 0; //Sets to null. Because it sets the next k to be evaluated, setting this to null doesn't work.
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(digitsGroup); //debug

    //Adds '-' for gramar, cleans all null values, joins the group's elements into a string
    for (var l = 0; l < digitsGroupLen; l++) {
        if (digitsGroup[l][1] && digitsGroup[l][2]) {
            digitsGroup[l][1] += '-';
        }
        digitsGroup[l].filter(function (e) {return e !== null});
        digitsGroup[l] = digitsGroup[l].join('');
    }

    console.log(digitsGroup); //debug

    //Adds thousand, millions, billion and etc to the respective string.
    var posfix = [null, 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion', 'quintillion', 'sextillion'];
    if (digitsGroupLen > 1) {
        var posfixRange = posfix.splice(0, digitsGroupLen).reverse();
        for (var m = 0; m < digitsGroupLen - 1; m++) { //'-1' prevents adding a null posfix to the last group
            if (digitsGroup[m]) {
                digitsGroup[m] += ' ' + posfixRange[m];
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(digitsGroup); //debug

    //Joins all the string into one and returns it
    return digitsGroup.join(' ');

} //End of numToWords function
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};
function hi() {
        var hold = 'No value';
    var inputValue = input.value;
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(visits[inputValue]);
    hold = numToWords(visits[inputValue].visits);
    output.innerHTML = hold;
}
var button = document.getElementById('changeText');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var input = document.getElementById('numinput');


input.addEventListener('input', hi);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

function hi(firstName){
//if the name doesn't exist it will give an error, so better make a check
  if(visits[firstName]!=null){
    var numberOfVisits=visits[firstName].visits; //this is the number of the visits for a given name
    //then you can use a switch or whatever you want to show your message
    var words=['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
    return words[numberOfVisits];
  }
}

var rolsResult=hi('Rols');
console.log(rolsResult);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:
1. Check if the key exists in the object, if yes convert the value into text equivalent, say from 1 to `one`.
2. If not, return 'Welcome'.

```js
var visits = {
  'Mike': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Roland': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Chiks': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Rols': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

function hi(name) {
  var v = visits[name];
  return v ? arr[(v.visits)-1]: 'Welcome';
}

console.log(hi('Mike'));
```